# trigonometric equation containing sin(x) and x

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem solving the following trigonometric equation and would be happy for any help.

$$\sin(2x) = 3,5x$$

What I tried is:

$$2\sin(x)\cos(x) = 3,5x\\                                                                                   
 2\sin(x)(1-\sin(x)) = 3,5x\\                                                                                                     
 2\sin(x)-2\sin^2(x) = 3,5x\\                                                                                                                                                             
 \sin(x)-\sin^2(x) = 1,75x$$

And now I don't know what to do ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: Note that $$\cos x\neq 1-\sin x$$ so you cannot make that substitution.

Comment: Hint: $x=0$ is obviously a solution. Can you prove that there are no others?

Comment: Thank you all! Andrew Chin: by using the Ttrigonometric  pythagoras sinx_i^2(x) +cosx_i^2(x) =1 I concluded cos(x) = 1-sin(x) is there a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one solution: $x=0$.

Note that if $|x|>\frac27$, then it is impossible for this equality to hold since $|3.5x|>1\geq|\sin(2x)|$.

Now use the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ to show that there is no other solution in $\left(\frac{-2}7,\frac27\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't Taylor expansion an overkill here? All that is needed is $|\sin x|\le |x|$, so for $x\ne 0$ we have $|\sin 2x|\le |2x|\lt |3.5 x|$

Comment: @StinkingBishop How do you conclude $\sin{x}\leq x$ without derivatives or expansions?

Comment: Depending on which level the OP is studying trigonometry, but as the sine is first introduced, you have a point on the unit circle, and $|\sin x|$ is the distance of the point from the $x$ axis, while $|x|$ itself (if taken in radians) is the *length of the arc* from the point to $(1,0)$, which is geometrically "obviously" longer than the straight distance to $(1,0)$, which is still longer than the distance to the $x$ axis. Surely, here I use a convenient equivalent definition of sine which makes it easy to "see" the inequality (sweep some details under the carpet) - but OP may appreciate it.